# Folland's real analysis, Dirac $\delta$-function as the Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

In Folland's real analysis, it writes

> *Nonexample*: Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure and $\upsilon$ the point mass at 0 on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$. Clearly $\upsilon \perp \mu$. The **nonexistent** Radon-Nikodym derivative $dv/d\mu$ is popularly known as the Dirac $\delta$-function.

I'm confused why is the Radon-Nikodym derivative $dv/d\mu$ said to be nonexistent? Isn't it just the Dirac $\delta$-function as the author later said?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $\mu(\{0\})=0$ but $v(\{0\})=1$.

Comment: There is not a thing as the Dirac delta function in the sense of a measurable function $\delta:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The Dirac $\delta$ is a measure on sets of $\mathbb{R}$, that asking $1$ to every set containing $0$, and zero otherwise (It can also be considered as a *generalized* function of distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we consider $\delta$ as a measurable function $\Bbb R\to\overline{\Bbb R}$. How? The only reasonable way would be to say, $\delta:x\mapsto\begin{cases}+\infty&x=0\\0&x\neq0\end{cases}$. But then $\delta$ is a.e. zero and it's obvious that the induced measure $A\mapsto\int_A\delta\,\mathrm{d}\mu$ would just be the zero measure, which is **not** equal to $\nu$.

No Radon-Nikodym derivative exists because $\nu$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing the concepts, but may I ask what is "point mass at 0" and why $\upsilon \perp \mu$?

Comment: @sam2018 The point mass (n.b. "Mass" is the German word for "measure", it's intuitive to view measures as assigning mass, this fits with the 'density' analogies too) refers to the "Dirac measure" (also denoted $\delta$) which is defined through $\delta=\chi_{\{0\}}$; the indicator function of a point (assigning mass to that point and nowhere else)

Comment: We have $\nu\perp\mu$ because we can partition $\Bbb R=A\sqcup B$ where $\mu|_B\equiv0$, $\nu|_A\equiv0$; choose $A=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and $B=\{0\}$

Comment: So $\int_S f(x)\delta (x-x_0)d\mu(x) := \int_S f(x)d v(x) = f(x_0)\delta_{x_0}(S) = f(x_0) 1_S(x_0)$, and the leftmost expression is just a confusing/abuse of notation purely symbolic expression to represent what is on the right?

Comment: @lightxbulb yeah I guess so? $\delta$ is meaningful in things like distribution theory (apparently) but I don't ever work with it. From my view point, it's weird notation for "evaluation at a point" *but* take that with a pinch of salt because I never actually need to use it myself. It's convenient notation for point-mass measures too

Comment: @FShrike Even for distributions $\delta_{x_0}$ is supposed to be the evaluation functional $\delta_{x_0}(f) = f(x_0)$, but it is not a regular distribution, i.e. there exists no function $\delta$ such that $\delta_{x_0}(f) = \int \delta(x-x_0) f(x)\,dx$. I just keep reading physics and engineering books with the above abuse of notation and it keeps tripping me up. There are reproducing kernels in reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces that behave like $\delta$ though, in that case I guess one could treat it in this manner.